# What's the shortcut to move a line up in Netbeans

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, eclipse, netbeans

I'm looking for a keyboard shortcut to move a line up or down.

Equivalent to Eclipe's Alt+up/Alt+down.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_editor_keyboard_shortcuts_are_available%3F

I can't seem to find a similar one in NetBeans.

http://ui.netbeans.org/docs/hi/shortcuts/shortcut.html

Is this feature hidden somewhere?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's:

```
Alt + Shift + up/down
```

So quite similar to eclipse

Answer (score 5):

For those who use `Linux`, `Alt + Shift + up/down` could be a shortcut for changing windows, so instead <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> or <kbd>Page Down</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

On Mac with NetBeans 8.2 the shortcuts are a little different:

```
Alt + Shift + up/down  -it duplicates the line
Ctrl + Shift + up/down  -it moves the line
```

Answer (score 1):

Just click on the **"Source"** menu, in the menu bar, and look for the items **"Move Up"** and **"Move Down"** or **"Move Code Element Up"** and **"Move Code Element Down"**. They should show the shortcut/accelerator for your platform.